# I want to use the result data of API to another JS variable by export

Tags: node.js, http-post

I'm new to nodejs, can some one help to fix. Below is the code which executes successful and display a console log when execute. But instead of printing here I want to export and use in another js files when required.

```
var https = require('https');

var spids={};
var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'x-ivx-api-key': '',
    'x-ivx-api-token': ''
};
var dataString = JSON.stringify({"sps":[0]});
var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'hostname': '',
  'path': '',
    headers: headers,
    body: dataString
  }
var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
  var chunks = [];
  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });
  res.on("end", function (chunk) {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    str=body.toString();
    spids["array"] = JSON.parse(str).data.sps;
    spids["array"].forEach(function (a) {
      //console.log("Here a means:",a.organization.id);
      a.name = ['name', 'id'].map(function (k) { return a[k]; }).join(' ');
      a.organization.name = ['name', 'id'].map(function (k) { return a.organization[k]; }).join(' ');
    });
   
    spids = JSON.stringify(spids,null,"\t");
    console.log(spids);
   
  return spids;
  });
  res.on("error", function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
});
req.write(dataString);
req.end();
module.exports.req = req;
```

I want to call and use it in separate js file.

```
const spidlist = require('./jsons/getSPIDlist');   
var s= await spidlist.req;
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can restructure you code as:

```js
var https = require("https");

const getSpids = () => {
  var spids = {};
  var headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "x-ivx-api-key": "",
    "x-ivx-api-token": "",
  };
  var dataString = JSON.stringify({ sps: [0] });
  var options = {
    method: "POST",
    hostname: "",
    path: "",
    headers: headers,
    body: dataString,
  };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    https.request(options, function (res) {
      var chunks = [];
      res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
      });
      res.on("end", function (chunk) {
        var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        str = body.toString();
        spids["array"] = JSON.parse(str).data.sps;
        spids["array"].forEach(function (a) {
          //console.log("Here a means:",a.organization.id);
          a.name = ["name", "id"]
            .map(function (k) {
              return a[k];
            })
            .join(" ");
          a.organization.name = ["name", "id"]
            .map(function (k) {
              return a.organization[k];
            })
            .join(" ");
        });

        spids = JSON.stringify(spids, null, "\t");
        console.log(spids);

        resolve(spids)
      });
      res.on("error", function (error) {
        console.error(error);
        reject(error)
      });
    });
  });
};

module.exports = getSpids
```

I haven't tested this piece of code but you should be able to use it as:

```js
const spidlist = require('./jsons/getSPIDlist');   
var s= await spidlist();
console.log(s);
```